# How do i get docker registry username and password in gitlab.com?

Tags: docker, gitlab, passwords, registry

I want to login to docker registry in gitlab.com using ansible play, but how   do i get docker registry username and  password in gitlab?

Is it same as gitlab.com username and password?

Comment: When you say docker registry, which registry are you referring to? Docker Hub or GitLab's own registry?

Comment: Because of the vast amount of information on the internet and Stack Overflow, it often takes just a simple search or two to find them. Please include the research that you have done and what you have tried.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Registry credentials in GitLab are the same as the repositories they belong to. So, you can use your GitLab.com username and password.

That said, you should probably create a [personal access token](https://gitlab.com/profile/personal_access_tokens) with only `read_registry` permissions to use with Ansible, instead of literally using your account credentials, to limit what Ansible can do. And, you can revoke the token if it leaks.

Documentation: [Personal access tokens](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html)